# Azure Function Logging with Serilog to Application Insights

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog, ilogger

We use *Azure Function V3* with dot net core 3.1 and log traces and events to *Application Insights*.
This works quite fine. But we want to add object data to the log payload and therefore we use *Serilog*.

If we use the `ILogger` interface from `namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` the object won't be serialized correct.

```cs
_logger.LogInformation("Test {@model}", testmodel);
```

If we use the *Serilog* interface it works and the data will be serialized in *Application Insights*:

```cs
logger.Information("Test Serilog {@model}", testmodel);
```

[image: Serilog]

The `Startup.cs` looks like that:

```cs
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(), TelemetryConverter.Traces, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
      .Destructure.ToMaximumCollectionCount(10)
      .Destructure.ToMaximumDepth(4)
      .CreateLogger();
    builder.Services.AddLogging(c => c.AddSerilog(logger));
    // Add other services
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you set on using Serilog? Otherwise the easier (and officially documented) approach might be to use an AppInsights TelemetryClient inside your Function. This way you can track all kinds of events and telemetry to AppInsights:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#log-custom-telemetry-in-c-functions

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try this asap.

Comment: It works fine with the TelemetryClient - thank you.
Those articles also helped me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services and 
https://camerondwyer.com/2020/05/26/how-to-report-on-serialized-json-object-data-in-application-insights-azure-monitor-using-kusto/

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to take a look at the Arcus Observability library.  It allows you to use the ILogger interface to write logs, custom metrics, etc... to Application Insights (using Serilog).
https://observability.arcus-azure.net/

https://observability.arcus-azure.net/guidance/use-with-dotnet-and-functions.html